# Is there a way to add a checklist to each new card without having to type the title and check list items each time?

Tags: trello

For each new card I create, I would like to have the same check list.  Is there a way to save a checklist so that I can add it to each card without having to type the title and each checklist item for each card?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a card that you could call "my template card". On it create the checklist, and any other feature you need. Then, every time you need a new card, just copy it, and rename it to what you actaully want.

Comment: What if I add cards in a batch and on top of that, I have a combo of checklists that I don't always use on every card?

Answer (score 1):

I've written a script that allows you to automatically add checklists to new cards, and will bulk update existing cards too - details here: http://www.littlebluemonkey.com/pimp-your-trello-cards/